# Highchart not displaying data at some zoom levels

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here is a fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/8jMfa/6/

Can someone explain this behavior to me? I've been wrestling with it all day.
It seems to render at some zoom levels but not others.

Could it be because the time series is irregular at some points?

```
var parsedData = {};
    parsedData.Highcharts = {};  

parsedData.Highcharts.series= [{"name":"Wind Direction","data":[[1325397600000,90],[1325419200000,90],[1325440800000],[1325484000000],[1325505600000,290],[1325527200000,290],[1325570400000,70],[1325592000000,90],[1325613600000,50],[1325656800000,270],[1325678400000,260],[1325700000000,270],[1325743200000],[1325764800000,270],[1325786400000,270],[1325829600000,300],[1325851200000,280],[1325872800000,280],[1325916000000,0],[1325937600000,300],[1325959200000,330],[1326002400000,30],[1326024000000,0],[1326045600000,0],[1326088800000,300],[1326110400000,300],[1326132000000,270],[1326175200000,260],[1326196800000,220],[1326218400000,0],[1326261600000,300],[1326283200000,270],[1326304800000,230],[1326348000000,250],[1326369600000,250],[1326391200000,270],[1326434400000,250],[1326456000000,270],[1326477600000,260],[1326520800000,300],[1326542400000,300],[1326564000000,300],[1326607200000,270],[1326628800000,270],[1326650400000,280],[1326693600000,290],[1326715200000,300],[1326736800000,280],[1326780000000,280],[1326801600000,280],[1326823200000,300],[1326866400000,300],[1326888000000,300],[1326909600000,270],[1326952800000,220],[1326974400000,90],[1326996000000,300],[1327039200000,300],[1327060800000,270],[1327082400000,0],[1327125600000,280],[1327147200000,300],[1327168800000,260],[1327212000000,300],[1327233600000,250],[1327255200000,0],[1327298400000,20],[1327320000000,20],[1327341600000,360],[1327384800000,0],[1327406400000,360],[1327428000000,360],[1327471200000,50],[1327492800000,0],[1327514400000,50],[1327557600000,120],[1327579200000,100],[1327600800000],[1327644000000,90],[1327665600000,90],[1327687200000,100],[1327730400000,30],[1327752000000,360],[1327773600000,360],[1327838400000,30],[1327860000000,30],[1327903200000,30],[1327924800000,30],[1327946400000,40],[1327989600000,320],[1328011200000,30],[1328032800000,270],[1328076000000],[1328097600000,90],[1328119200000,270],[1328162400000,270],[1328184000000,270],[1328205600000],[1328248800000,320],[1328270400000,320],[1328292000000,270],[1328335200000,280],[1328356800000,280],[1328378400000,270],[1328421600000,270],[1328443200000,70],[1328464800000,90],[1328508000000,130],[1328529600000,340],[1328551200000,0],[1328594400000,300],[1328616000000,300],[1328637600000,290],[1328680800000],[1328702400000],[1328724000000,300],[1328767200000,100],[1328788800000,50],[1328810400000,0],[1328853600000,0],[1328875200000,250],[1328896800000,0],[1328940000000,270],[1328961600000,90],[1328983200000],[1329026400000,100],[1329048000000,70],[1329069600000],[1329112800000,300],[1329134400000,300],[1329156000000,280],[1329199200000,300],[1329220800000],[1329242400000,30],[1329285600000,270],[1329307200000,270],[1329328800000],[1329372000000],[1329393600000],[1329415200000,260],[1329458400000,290],[1329480000000,260],[1329501600000,300],[1329544800000,90],[1329566400000,150],[1329588000000,250],[1329631200000,0],[1329652800000,290],[1329674400000,290],[1329717600000],[1329739200000],[1329760800000,220],[1329804000000,270],[1329825600000,270],[1329847200000,280],[1329890400000,220],[1329912000000,210],[1329933600000,180],[1329976800000,270],[1329998400000,270],[1330020000000,250],[1330063200000,230],[1330106400000,280],[1330149600000,270],[1330171200000,270],[1330192800000],[1330236000000,270],[1330257600000,270],[1330279200000,270],[1330322400000,300],[1330344000000,250],[1330365600000,270],[1330408800000],[1330430400000],[1330452000000,100],[1330495200000,280],[1330516800000,300],[1330538400000,280],[1330581600000,270],[1330603200000,270],[1330624800000,250],[1330668000000,270],[1330689600000,180],[1330711200000,310],[1330754400000,180],[1330776000000,270],[1330797600000],[1330840800000,270],[1330862400000,270],[1330884000000,270],[1330927200000,360],[1330948800000,100],[1330970400000,90],[1331013600000,90],[1331035200000,90],[1331056800000,100],[1331100000000,120],[1331121600000,120],[1331143200000,90],[1331186400000,300],[1331208000000,300],[1331229600000,250],[1331272800000,240],[1331294400000],[1331316000000,270],[1331359200000,320],[1331380800000,230],[1331402400000,260],[1331467200000,260],[1331488800000,270],[1331532000000,270],[1331553600000,270],[1331575200000,270],[1331618400000,300],[1331640000000,270],[1331661600000,270],[1331704800000,270],[1331726400000,270],[1331748000000,60],[1331791200000,250],[1331812800000,260],[1331834400000,270],[1331877600000,280],[1331899200000,280],[1331920800000,260],[1331964000000,240],[1331985600000,250],[1332007200000,260],[1332050400000,270],[1332072000000,260],[1332093600000,270],[1332136800000,270],[1332158400000,240],[1332180000000,250],[1332223200000,250],[1332244800000,250],[1332266400000,270],[1332309600000,250],[1332331200000,260],[1332352800000,0],[1332396000000,280],[1332417600000,230],[1332439200000,270],[1332482400000,290],[1332504000000,270],[1332525600000,280],[1332568800000,280],[1332590400000,90],[1332612000000,260],[1332676800000,280],[1332698400000,310],[1332741600000,290],[1332763200000,270],[1332784800000,270],[1332828000000,50],[1332849600000,290],[1332871200000,270],[1332914400000,270],[1332936000000,300],[1332957600000],[1333000800000,0],[1333022400000,270],[1333044000000,270],[1333087200000,270],[1333108800000,270],[1333130400000,300],[1333173600000,270],[1333195200000,300],[1333216800000,300],[1333260000000,290],[1333281600000,290],[1333303200000,300],[1333346400000,300],[1333368000000,300],[1333389600000,290],[1333432800000,260],[1333454400000,330],[1333476000000,130],[1333519200000,270],[1333540800000,260],[1333562400000,220],[1333605600000,280],[1333627200000,250],[1333648800000,260],[1333692000000,300],[1333713600000,100],[1333735200000,70],[1333778400000,0],[1333800000000,270],[1333821600000,260],[1333864800000,300],[1333886400000,180],[1333908000000,240],[1333951200000,120],[1333972800000,300],[1333994400000,130],[1334037600000,90],[1334059200000,120],[1334080800000,150],[1334124000000,120],[1334145600000,120],[1334167200000,190],[1334210400000,120],[1334232000000,100],[1334253600000],[1334296800000,90],[1334318400000,50],[1334340000000,0],[1334383200000,90],[1334404800000,150],[1334426400000,120],[1334469600000,240],[1334491200000,250],[1334512800000,260],[1334556000000,270],[1334577600000,270],[1334599200000,260],[1334642400000,300],[1334664000000,300],[1334685600000,180],[1334728800000,60],[1334750400000,60],[1334772000000,90],[1334815200000,70],[1334836800000,70],[1334858400000,60],[1334901600000,70],[1334923200000,40],[1334944800000,30],[1334988000000,70],[1335009600000,90],[1335031200000,90],[1335096000000,20],[1335117600000,20],[1335160800000,0],[1335182400000,0],[1335204000000,100],[1335247200000,360],[1335268800000,120],[1335290400000,90],[1335333600000,330],[1335355200000,90],[1335376800000,90],[1335420000000,270],[1335441600000,280],[1335463200000,220],[1335506400000,120],[1335528000000,180],[1335549600000,260],[1335592800000,270],[1335614400000,270],[1335636000000,10],[1335679200000,280],[1335700800000,70],[1335722400000,50],[1335765600000,80],[1335787200000,90],[1335808800000],[1335852000000,280],[1335873600000,80],[1335895200000,120],[1335938400000,100],[1335960000000,100],[1335981600000,120],[1336024800000,300],[1336046400000,300],[1336068000000,0],[1336111200000,120],[1336132800000,120],[1336154400000,270],[1336197600000,270],[1336219200000,90],[1336240800000,80],[1336284000000,80],[1336305600000,90],[1336370400000,300],[1336392000000,290],[1336456800000,300],[1336478400000,120],[1336500000000],[1336564800000,90],[1336586400000,120],[1336651200000,240],[1336672800000,250],[1336716000000,250],[1336737600000,250],[1336759200000,260],[1336802400000,270],[1336824000000,290],[1336845600000,280],[1336888800000,300],[1336910400000,200],[1336932000000,250],[1336975200000,170],[1336996800000,250],[1337018400000,180],[1337061600000,210],[1337083200000,140],[1337104800000,270],[1337148000000,360],[1337169600000,150],[1337191200000,300],[1337234400000,240],[1337256000000,250],[1337277600000,250],[1337320800000],[1337364000000,150],[1337407200000,120],[1337428800000,150],[1337450400000,120],[1337493600000,100],[1337515200000,80],[1337536800000,150],[1337580000000,260],[1337601600000,20],[1337623200000,40],[1337666400000,270],[1337688000000,60],[1337709600000,90],[1337752800000,70],[1337774400000,90],[1337796000000,110],[1337839200000,270],[1337860800000,270],[1337882400000,0],[1337925600000,280],[1337947200000,110],[1337968800000,0],[1338012000000,230],[1338033600000,150],[1338055200000,150],[1338098400000,100],[1338120000000,200],[1338141600000,200],[1338184800000,300],[1338206400000,260],[1338228000000,90],[1338271200000,90],[1338292800000,60],[1338314400000,220],[1338357600000,60],[1338379200000,100],[1338400800000,360],[1338444000000,300],[1338465600000,340],[1338487200000,240],[1338530400000,90],[1338552000000,180],[1338573600000,270],[1338616800000,300],[1338638400000,90],[1338660000000,90],[1338724800000,250],[1338746400000,250],[1338789600000,260],[1338811200000,90],[1338832800000,30],[1338876000000,90],[1338897600000,90],[1338919200000,240],[1338962400000,300],[1338984000000,240],[1339005600000,200],[1339048800000,0],[1339070400000,150],[1339092000000,150],[1339135200000,0],[1339156800000,90],[1339178400000,270],[1339221600000,90],[1339243200000,300],[1339264800000,270],[1339308000000,60],[1339329600000,30],[1339351200000,120],[1339394400000,0],[1339416000000,30],[1339437600000,90],[1339480800000,30],[1339502400000,270],[1339524000000,90],[1339567200000,0],[1339588800000,120],[1339610400000,160],[1339653600000,330],[1339675200000,250],[1339696800000,270],[1339740000000,20],[1339761600000,70],[1339783200000,300],[1339826400000,0],[1339848000000,300],[1339869600000,300],[1339912800000,300],[1339934400000,330],[1339956000000,360],[1339999200000,200],[1340020800000,170],[1340042400000,250],[1340085600000,250],[1340107200000,260],[1340128800000,270],[1340172000000,300],[1340193600000,200],[1340215200000,120],[1340258400000,0],[1340280000000,140],[1340301600000,80],[1340344800000,100],[1340366400000,90],[1340388000000,110],[1340431200000,90],[1340474400000,120],[1340517600000,150],[1340539200000,120],[1340560800000,90],[1340604000000,280],[1340625600000,270],[1340647200000,250],[1340690400000,310],[1340712000000,280],[1340733600000,270],[1340776800000,270],[1340798400000,280],[1340820000000,90],[1340884800000,80],[1340906400000,300],[1340949600000,270],[1340971200000,280],[1340992800000,220],[1341036000000,100],[1341057600000,240],[1341079200000,180],[1341122400000,180],[1341144000000,130],[1341165600000,240],[1341208800000,0],[1341230400000,210],[1341252000000,60],[1341295200000,0],[1341316800000,110],[1341338400000,140],[1341381600000,0],[1341403200000,90],[1341424800000,130],[1341468000000,130],[1341489600000,120],[1341511200000,120],[1341554400000,90],[1341576000000,90],[1341597600000,60],[1341640800000,180],[1341662400000,180],[1341684000000,180],[1341727200000,0],[1341748800000,0],[1341770400000,0],[1341813600000,270],[1341835200000,90],[1341856800000,90],[1341900000000,90],[1341921600000,90],[1341943200000,90],[1341986400000,240],[1342008000000,180],[1342029600000,300],[1342072800000,300],[1342094400000,300],[1342116000000,0],[1342159200000,270],[1342180800000,250],[1342202400000,230],[1342245600000,270],[1342267200000,120],[1342288800000,260],[1342332000000,0],[1342353600000,270],[1342375200000,260],[1342418400000],[1342440000000,230],[1342461600000,260],[1342504800000,270],[1342526400000,270],[1342548000000,250],[1342591200000,90],[1342612800000,270],[1342634400000,120],[1342677600000,0],[1342699200000,0],[1342720800000,270],[1342764000000,240],[1342785600000,90],[1342807200000,100],[1342850400000,30],[1342872000000,130],[1342893600000,270],[1342936800000,300],[1342958400000,200],[1342980000000,170],[1343023200000,260],[1343044800000,180],[1343066400000,290],[1343109600000,250],[1343131200000,200],[1343152800000,230],[1343196000000,210],[1343217600000,230],[1343239200000,30],[1343282400000,270],[1343304000000,280],[1343325600000,120],[1343368800000,240],[1343390400000,90],[1343412000000,100],[1343455200000,0],[1343476800000,70],[1343498400000,0],[1343541600000,200],[1343563200000,100],[1343584800000,100],[1343628000000,280],[1343649600000,180],[1343671200000,120],[1343714400000,120],[1343736000000,150],[1343757600000,300],[1343800800000,270],[1343822400000,260],[1343844000000,140],[1343908800000,120],[1343930400000,90],[1343973600000,180],[1343995200000,260],[1344016800000,240],[1344060000000,280],[1344081600000,240],[1344103200000,180],[1344146400000,270],[1344168000000,210],[1344189600000,240],[1344232800000,230],[1344254400000,360],[1344276000000,90],[1344319200000,210],[1344340800000,270],[1344362400000,250],[1344405600000,270],[1344427200000,90],[1344448800000,50]],"yAxis":0,"color":"#80699B","visible":true,"dataGrouping":{"enabled":false}}];

parsedData.Highcharts.yAxis = [{"title":{"text":"Wind Direction"},"lineWidth":1,"lineColor":"#80699B","tickWidth":1,"offset":25,"opposite":false,"allowDecimals":false,"showEmpty":false,"labels":{"style":{"color":"#80699B"}}}];

    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
chart : {

                    spacingRight : 0,
                    spacingBottom : 3,
                    spacingLeft : 0,
                    //reflow : true,
                    renderTo : 'container',
                    type : 'line',
                    //shadow : true,
                    //alignTicks : false,
                    //turboThreshold: 30000,

                    //plotBackgroundImage: 'http://www.dawnbreaker.com/forums/navy09/images/gradient_bg.png',
                    //marginLeft:50,
                    //zoomType: 'x',
                    //marginRight : 50,
                    //marginBottom : 25,
                    //marginTop : 50,
                    //marginBottom : 75,
                    minPadding : .5,
                    //height : 360,
                    //width : 1000,
                    events : {
                    //    load : Highcharts.drawTable
                    },
                    style : {
                        fontFamily : 'serif',
                        fontSize : 10
                    }
                },
                navigator : {
                    series : {
                        color : '#2B5C8A'
                    }
                },
                rangeSelector : {
                    inputEnabled : false,
                    buttonTheme : {// styles for the buttons
                        fill : 'none',
                        stroke : 'none',
                        style : {
                            color : '#1F3243',
                            fontWeight : 'bold'
                        },
                        states : {
                            hover : {
                                stroke : '#262F2F'
                            },
                            select : {
                                style : {
                                    color : 'white'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    buttons : [{
                        type : 'day',
                        count : 3,
                        text : '3d'
                    }, {
                        type : 'week',
                        count : 1,
                        text : '1w'
                    }, {
                        type : 'month',
                        count : 1,
                        text : '1m'
                    }, {
                        type : 'month',
                        count : 6,
                        text : '6m'
                    }, {
                        type : 'year',
                        count : 1,
                        text : '1y'
                    }, {
                        type : 'all',
                        text : 'All'
                    }],
                    selected : 4
                },

                xAxis : {
                    type : 'datetime',

                    //ordinal: false,

                    dateTimeLabelFormats : {
                        //second : '%b %e',
                        //    minute : '%b %e, %l%P',
                        hour : '%b %e, %l%P',
                        /*            day : '%b %e, %Y',
                         week : '%b %e, %Y',
                         month : '%b %Y',
                         */
                        year : '%Y'
                    },
                    title : {
                        text : null
                    },

                    labels : {
                        style : {
                            color : '#eee',
                            fontSize : 9
                        }
                    },
                    lineColor : '#eee',
                    tickColor : '#eee',
                    //tickPixelInterval : 150
                },
                legend : {
                    enabled : true,
                    //floating:true,
                    layout : 'horizontal',
                    align : 'center',
                    //y:25,
                    //x:50,
                    backgroundColor : 'grey',
                    shadow : true,
                    verticalAlign : 'top',
                    borderColor : '#eee',
                    padding : 10,
                    borderWidth : 2,
                    itemMarginTop : 3,
                    itemMarginBottom : 3,

                    itemStyle : {
                        cursor : 'pointer',
                        color : '#eee',
                        lineHeight : '14px'
                    },
                    itemHoverStyle : {
                        color : '#333'
                    },

                },
                column : {
                    borderColor : "#eee",
                    borderRadius : 1,
                    shadow : false
                },

                plotOptions : {

                    series:
                    {
                        //dataGrouping:false,
                        connectNulls : true,
                        //cropThreshold: 3000,
                        animation:false
                    },
                    line:{
                        //dataGrouping:false,
                        //connectNulls : true,
                        animation:false

                    },    
                        //compare:  document.getElementsByName('comparison')[0].value, /*function() {
                        //        return (document.getElementsByName('comparison')[0].value);
                        //       },*/
                        animation : {
                            duration : 2000,
                            easing : 'swing'

                        }

                },

                series : parsedData.Highcharts.series,
                yAxis : parsedData.Highcharts.yAxis

    }) });​
```

Comment: Make sure that your dates are in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The issue was that some dates had no Y-values associated with them. After I filtered those out (server-side) the problem was fixed.